# How can i use formRemote feature in my grails app

Tags: grails

Iam formRemote in a gsp and calling a controller method, inside that method iam calling a sevice class and there iam doing my save action. But the problem is my update div is not working after a successful saving

Comment: Could you show your gsp page code. then only i can understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

- You form should like this

  ```
  <g:formRemote  method="post"
       update="updateThisDiv"
      name="formRemote" url="[ controller: 'main', action:'myAction']">
      //your form fields
  </g:formRemote>

  <div id="updateThisDiv"></div>
  ```
- "updateThisDiv" is the id of an html-object, that you want to render after submit (but it's not mandatory).

**Controller**

```
def myAction() {
  //TODO: your logic..
  render "Your view" //you can render jsp view, json etc..
}
```